# How should I deal with configuration by DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Actually I am working with date ranges and every day at certain time the modifications should be locked down for that day. So after that time I should not be able to add a task for the actual day, just for the next day. This lockdown time should be stored in the configuration and I should be able to change it in the admin settings.

What is the proper way to inject this lockdown time into the task scheduler? Should I add a config repo, or should I inject it by the instantiation of the scheduler? Should configuration be part of the domain?

Comment: What is your domain exactly? Task scheduling? Is eventual consistency acceptable (e.g. lockdown time gets updated at the same time a new task is scheduled)?

Comment: @plalx Does it matter? It was just an example. Actually it is complicated something like task scheduling, but not exactly. It does not have a real business impact, so it is fine to accept the new task if the settings are changed while adding it.

Comment: " it is fine to accept the new task if the settings are changed while adding it." That's extremely important to know in order to get the model right. I'd also want to know the motivation behind these lockdowns? How are they an important aspect of the business?

Comment: @plalx I'll try to explain it through this task analogy, but I am not sure it is possible. You are a customer and there are service providers (SP hereafter) which can do tasks added by the customers. Every morning these SPs get the task lists they have to do the actual day. After that they don't interact with the system, so they cannot receive new tasks for that day. That's why the day is locked down for that day after the lockdown time is reached. Note that the actual problem is somewhat different but lead to the same lockdown solution.

Comment: @plalx I am not sure, but I think I have a technical problem rather than a modelling problem. Check the comments under alltej's answer! Ohh, it is fine to accept the tasks added while changing the settings, because the settings rarely change, SPs start working the same time every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a lockdown time should be part of the domain model, as it is a business rule that needs capturing.

> What is the proper way to inject this lockdown time into the task scheduler? Should I add a config repo, or should I inject it by the instantiation of the scheduler?

You've already considered passing values into a constructor, but you could also pass it to the method call itself. For example (taken from the comments to alltej's answer):

```
user.ScheduleTask(label, begin, end, lockdownTime) {
    // check lockdownTime and decide whether to schedule the task 
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
// taskSchedulingService.cs (ctor takes in a configRepo and userRepo)

public void ScheduleTask(userId, label, begin, end) {
    var user = userRepo.GetById(userId)
    var lockdownTime = configRepo.GetLockdownTime()
    user.ScheduleTask(label, begin, end, lockdownTime)
}
```

> Should configuration be part of the domain?

Hard to answer this, it depends on the domain. I'd default to "no" as it usually isn't, but then maybe you have a domain that is all about configuration :) Most of the time you will just be reading some values from a database or file when the app starts and using these values to create your services / objects. In this scenario the configuration itself isn't part of the domain - the domain would just need the values, i.e. in your scenario the domain would have a lockdownTime concept but wouldn't care where it came from necessarily.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of something like this too. Maybe the already long argument list was the cause I did not choose this, but I think you are right, this is a proper solution. I'll wait, maybe somebody has a solution for the constructor injection as well.

Answer (score 1):

The lock down is part of your business rules. Thus, it should be considered part of your domain services. This lock down service is a business function that, given a set of values, will determine if add or update of task is allowed.

I would probably do it something like:

```
public class LockdownService: ILockdownService{
     public LockdownService(ILockdownRepo lockDownRepo){
         ...
    }

    public bool isLock(){
         //do logic here
    }

    //replace object with your model representation
    public object GetLockdownTime(){
         ...
    }
}


public class TaskSchedulerService{
     public TaskSchedulerService(IUserRepo userRepo, ILockdownService lockDownSvc, ITaskRepo taskRepo){
             ...
     }

    public void ScheduleTask(userId, label, begin, end) {
            var user = userRepo.GetById(userId)
            var lockdownTime = lockDownSvc.GetLockdownTime()
            //do lockdown logic


            //create task if all business rules are satisfied
            taskRepo.ScheduleTask(user.userId, label, begin, end);
    }       
}
```

If lockdown service requires info on a task, then you can also inject the task repo to lockdown service constructor.

Hope that gives you the idea.

Comment: Not really. Actually I already have something like that, but it is not clear where to inject and how to use that domain service. I would do something like `user.scheduleTask(label, begin, end)` - if I'd have a time to completely refactor the code - so in theory it should be injected into the domain object I guess by `userRepository.findById(userId)`. Is this okay? Feels weird to inject a service into a domain object, but I am really new to DDD, so it is maybe okay.

Comment: My main problem that the same `User` instance is reused by authentication. It has an `User.hasRole(role)` and an `User.isOwner(owner)` method. By installation there is a state when an `User` instance is authenticated, but there is no configuration yet, which means that the lockdown service cannot be injected into the `User` by instantiation. Ofc. this is bad design, but I guess the installation process should not be part of the domain. I am a bit lost by resolving this issue. I added a setter for injecting the lockdown service as workaround, but it is a really ugly hack. :D

Comment: I don't want this project to be perfect, but it would be nice to learn how to do this better at least in theory.

Comment: Don't inject the lockdown service to the User object. Instead create a TaskSchedulingService that takes the userRepo and lockdownService in the constructor.

Comment: @inf3rno updated answer. let me know if you have questions

Comment: Interesting. So you think the app service (instead of the `user.scheduleTask` should refuse the task if it violates the lockdown rule? Actually this might work, but I have to check it. I am not sure, wouldn't this result in an anaemic domain?

Comment: An anemic domain model is not an anti-pattern per se. In DDD, the most important concepts are the verbs (not the nouns). I think in your case, the TaskScheduler is a domain concept which can be built around behaviours/functions. Then you can have the user object as a pure data structure.

Comment: Thanks! Then this is a viable solution as well, but I prefer having objects instead of data structures in my domain. I'll accept the other answer if that is not a problem. :-)